# Automatically generating pour points along stream network?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, hydrology, stream-order

The following screenshot shows the results of a water flow analysis where I identified stream order via the Strahler method in ArcGIS.  Now I need to generate watersheds for 2nd order streams and above. The screenshot shows the areas I need to automatically generate pour points. I have tried using the stream link tool, although the resulting product generates watersheds for all stream links, not just those >= 2nd order.

How can I automatically generate pour points for >= 2nd order streams?

[image]

Comment: Last point of this Lines?

Comment: If it is about catchments, convert required streams (=>2) to raster using unique integer value, e.g. ObjectID. Use this raster as input in watershed tool

Comment: Aaron, are the streams pointed downhill? Dissolve by stream order and planarize and then use Feature Vertices to points with the 'to' option to get the pour points. I answered a question recently about this but can't seem to find it right now... there was an issue with connectivity that needed to be broken for some reason (but that may not be related here). You might need to do several dissolves/planarize: Dissolve all, copy several times, (copy1) only use order 1, (copy2) remove 1, planarize, only use order 2, (copy3) remove 1 & 2, planarize, only use 3...

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this but it should work:

1. Convert raster stream network to polylines using [Raster to Polyline](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/raster-to-polyline.htm)
2. [Intersect](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/intersect.htm) the stream network polylines using `output_type = 'POINT'`
3. [Select Layer By Attribute](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-attribute.htm) points with both stream order 2 and a lower stream order
4. Copy the selection to a new feature class using [Copy Features](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-features.htm)